# How to store dates in a database

Tags: excel, database, validation, analytics

I'm currently working on a data visualisation project. But for this project we don't have a proper database, i need to gather the data from multiple employees in an excel sheet and i'm not an expert in this. So, i want to structure the excel sheet in the best way possible that it will help in other future projects if we need to use it, not only our current project.

My question is:

Each project we have must go through 6 phases, and for each phase I have start and end date.

What is the best way to store the data, should i have all in columns like this

| Project_name | Phase1_start | Phase1_end | Phsse2_start | Phase2_end | Phase3_start | Phase3_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Or:

| Project_name | Phase | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

I want to structure the sheet in a way that it will always be useful to serve any purpose not only this dashboard.

Also, this might be converted to mysql database.

Comment: The second format with 4 columns is better. This is the format data should be in to create pivot tables and charts in excel, and visualizations in power bi. Also, it is very easy to convert the second format into the first format if you need to. It is more difficult to convert the first format into the second format.

Comment: I agree with @kevin and think he should write this as an answer.